# Using Dynamic DNS for server reboots

Tags: dynamic-dns, availability

Basically, I want all the traffic to go to one server while the other reboots. Here's the environment:

```
Two or more VPS servers.
Same datacenter, but no internal ip or lan, and no shared ip.
```

I was thinking of this:

```
Update Dynanmic DNS settings to takeout server #1...
   redirecting all traffic to server #2.
Reboot server #1.
Update Dynamic DNS settings after reboot to allow #1 and #2 servers.
```

Is this a misuse of Dynamic DNS?

Comment: Because of DNS caching this is probably not going to work very well. I would suggest load balancing the two servers so that requests are directed to a VIP and can be handled by whichever server is available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We did not have much luck with this.  In your described scenario our clients did not reliably fail over using the method you describe.

I recommend a load balancer between the two servers so that requests are directed to a VIP and can be handled by whichever server is available.